# Why does Hibernate JPA lose the column names when queried?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

When I query Hibernate with a:

"select a from Account a", JAXRS gives me column names in my JSON, but when I execute this query:

"select a.firstName, a.lastName from Account a" the JSON simply contains the data without the column names.

For instance:

{ firstName: "Simon" }

becomes:

{ "Simon" }

Answer (score 1):

```
select a from Account a
```

is a JPQL query that returns a `List<Account>`. This list is thus serialized to JSON as an array of objects.

On the other hand,

```
select a.firstName, a.lastName from Account a
```

is a JPQL query that returns a `List<Object[]>`. This list is thus serialized to JSON as an array of arrays.

And finally,

```
select a.firstName from Account a
```

is a JPQL query that returns a `List<String>`. This list is thus serialized to JSON as an array of strings.